# SRWebsocket notification when send finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, socketrocket

I am trying to sync read and write operations when using Socket Rocket websocket library for iOS.

When reading packets is finished I get a call to DidReceiveMessage is called, however, I cannot find a way to get notified once a send: operation ends.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you